# Browser shows letsencrypt certificate expired when it isnt

Tags: nginx, ssl, lets-encrypt, certbot

Can someone please render me some assistance

I have an issue where when accessing the domain sg.simpple.app results in an error indicating that the cert date is invalid

[image]

However when running certbot certificates it shows that the certificate is already up to date and has ample time till expiry

[image]

I have also restarted the server through

1. systemctl restart nginx
2. systemctl restart php-fpm

My suspicion is that it is using the wrong certificate, can someone please guide me in solving this issue?

Comment: My browser shows the recent certificate, i.e. expiring 04/21. [SSLLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=www.sg.simpple.app&latest) also shows this not expired certificate. So what you describe can not be reproduced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was with the filepath in nano /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf.

As the previous letsencrypt certificate had different domains to the new letsencryp certificate generated it didnt replace the original certificate.

had to manually change the filepath in nano /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf.